# How to interpret json output of "npm list"

Tags: npm, npm-package

"npm list" tells what packages are installed, but if we output in JSON format, I cannot find a documentation to explain the format.

If we do `npm list -a -json`, it will list all non-global packages, and JSON data looks like:

```json
        "https-proxy-agent": {
          "version": "5.0.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent/-/https-proxy-agent-5.0.1.tgz",
          "overridden": false,
          "dependencies": {
            "agent-base": {
              "version": "6.0.2",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/agent-base/-/agent-base-6.0.2.tgz",
              "overridden": false,
              "dependencies": {
                "debug": {
                  "version": "4.3.4"
                }
              }
            },
            "debug": {
              "version": "4.3.4"
            }
          }
        },
```

The field `resolved` seems to indicate the package is installed. The package "debug" contains only a field of "version", which seems to indicate it's not installed. But I don't understand what `overridden: false` means.

If we do `npm list -g -a -json`, which lists all installed global packages. But the JSON format is slightly different:

```json
                            "wrap-ansi": {
                              "version": "8.1.0",
                              "overridden": false,
                              "dependencies": {
                                "ansi-styles": {
                                  "version": "6.2.1",
                                  "overridden": false
                                },
                                "string-width": {
                                  "version": "5.1.2"
                                },
                                "strip-ansi": {
                                  "version": "7.1.0"
                                }
                              }
                            }
```

The global list doesn't contain field "resolved". Should `overridden: false` indicate the package is installed?

Is there any documentation for which are all fields on `npm list -json` and meaning of every field?